# Showing real scale of the x-axis of a plot beside the axis label

Tags: plotting

I am using the code shown below to plot simple functions in which I am going to show the horizontal axes just with integer numbers. For correct presentation, I want to bring `* π/2` beside the axes, as also shown below. But I have put `* π/2` in the `AxesLabel` close to the `t` parameter. I am uncertain about the correctness of making the presentation this way. In fact, I do not know how I must show the exact scale of the horizontal axes when I want to present just integers on the ticks of plot. Any advice?

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 5 π/2},
  AxesLabel -> {Style["*π/2 t", Bold, 11], Style["C", Bold, 11]},
  LabelStyle-> {Bold, 11}, 
  Ticks-> {{{1Pi/2, Style["1"]},{3Pi/2, Style["3"]}, {5Pi/2, Style["5"]}}}];
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Wouldn't it be much better to include the $\pi/2$ factor in your axis tick labels? It would improve readability, at least in my opinion (i.e. `Ticks -> {{{Pi/2, Style["π/2"]}, {3 Pi/2, 
    Style["3π/2"]}, {5 Pi/2, Style["5π/2"]}}}`) to give [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bTZBp.png).

Comment: thanx. maybe!!!

Answer (score 3):

This turned out to be harder than I originally thought it would. The problem is that the x-axis is showing ticks for `t`, not the plotting variable `x`, so it is important that the relation between `t` and `x` be clearly shown. Further, the OP requested that the information about the relationship be displayed as an x-axis label. That condition caused trouble. I found I couldn't use the option `PlotLabels` to label the two curves because Mathematica insisted on overwriting the x-axis label with the cosine curve label. I had to resort to using callouts with some explicit positioning.

```
Plot[
  {Callout[Sin[x], Sin[x]], Callout[Cos[x], Cos[x], {5 π/2 + 1.2, .6}]},
  {x, 0, 5 π/2},
  LabelStyle -> {Bold, 12},
  AxesLabel -> {Row[{t, ", ", HoldForm[x = π/2], "\[ThinSpace]", t}], "C"},
  Ticks -> {{# π/2, #} & /@ Range[1, 5, 2], Automatic},
  ImagePadding -> All,
  ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image: plot]

The above conforms to my understanding of what the OP is asking for, but for myself I wouldn't make the plot that way. I would make it like this:

```
Plot[
  {Callout[Sin[π t/2 ], Sin[π t/2 ]], Callout[Cos[π t/2], Cos[π t/2], {5 + .9, .4}]},
  {t, 0, 5},
  LabelStyle -> {Bold, 11},
  AxesLabel -> {"t", "C"},
  ImagePadding -> All,
  ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image: plot]

I believe the second plot gets the point across better with simpler code. That's two pluses.

#### Update

I was really unhappy that I had not been able to post a solution using `PlotLabels` and `Placed`, so I returned to this problem, spent some time reading the documentation more carefully and trying this and that. After going down some wrong paths, I finally found a way.

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 5 π/2},
  LabelStyle -> {Bold, 12},
  AxesLabel -> {Row[{t, ", ", HoldForm[x = π/2], "\[ThinSpace]", t}], "C"},
  Ticks -> {{# π/2, #} & /@ Range[1, 5, 2], Automatic},
  PlotLabels -> 
    Placed["Expressions", {{Scaled[.2], Above}, {Scaled[.82], Above}}],
  ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image: plot]

The trick is to give the 2nd argument to `Placed`, the position specifier, as a list of two elements, one for each curve. Each element should be a pair of the form `{offset, position}`, where offset is a scaled distance along the x-axis and position indicates where the label should be positioned relative to curve at the offset (the usual `Above`, `Before`, etc.). This is never explicitly stated in the documentation, but there is an example of a list plot that hints at this solution.